# Django onetomany Query

Tags: django

Firstly, thanks to anyone who takes the time to answer this question.  I'm very new to Django and Programming (only been learning for a few months).

I've searched this forum for something similar to this query and also had a quick read of aggregation within Django to try and work it out.  I'm getting myself confused so thought I'd try asking the question because its driving me mad.

A very brief overview of what I'm trying to achieve.  I'm creating the menu system for my website, but doing this through the database so users can dynamically add / delete to the sites menu.  I've created two Models (with a onetomany relationship) to cover the Main Menu and Sub Menu elements of the sites navigation.

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    menu_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Menu Name")
    urlconf_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="URLConf Name")
    menu_position = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Menu Position", unique=True)
    has_sub_menu = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Sub Menu Linked")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Menu Active")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and

```
class Sub_Menu(models.Model):
    sub_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Sub Menu Name")
    urlconf_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Sub Menu URLConf Name")
    menu_position = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Sub Menu Position")
    menu_id = models.ForeignKey(Menu, related_name="name")
```

So, I've created a Main Menu table with "Home", "Contact Us", "Links" and "Classes".  The Sub Menu has "Dance Classes" linked to "Classes" and "Gymnastics Classes" also linked to "Classes".

Now, I'm struggling to work out how I can efficiently query these two tables to create a single dataset so I can iterate through this to generate the menu.  I.E. it needs to create a dataset as follows (using the "Menu Position" to order the elements of the dataset)

Menu, Classes, Dance Classes, Gymnastics Classes, Contact Us, Links.

My attempt is as follows in my View through two helper functions to create the dataset.

```
def get_menu():
    try:
        main_menu = Menu.objects.all().order_by('menu_position')
        return main_menu
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return None

def get_submenu(main_menu):
    submenu_dict = []
    for menu in main_menu:
        sub_menu = Sub_Menu.objects.filter(menu_id=menu.main_name).order_by('menu_position')
        submenu_dict.append(sub_menu)
       # pdb.set_trace()
    return submenu_dict
```

This doesn't work because I've cannot quite work out what its actually using in menu_id to reference the proper link to the main_menu. I think it would work once I have worked that out but I feel there is a much easier way to do this that I haven't probably read about yet.

Thanks for any assistance. Please bear in mind that I'm very new at this so if you could try and provide some explanation in your response I'd be very grateful.

Regards

Wayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great to see you're starting programmming, it's looking good.

You see, Django's [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) automatically adds an additional attribute to the *"parent"* model (in your case it'd be the `Menu` model) to access the related elements. You can [read about it here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

That way, if you have a certain `Menu` instance, you can access the related `Sub_Menu`s by using:

```
my_menu.sub_menu_set.all()
```

You can even use that directly in your template, although it's not the best idea performance-wise, but it works.

Comment: Thank you @José_Tomás_Tocino for taking the time to reply.  I've tried to apply that which seems to work but struggling to work out how best to store the data that comes back and how to then access it in the template.

I think i may re-write it to utilise a single model instead to make the looping easier.  The datasets are confusing me at the moment so think i need to re-read the python datasets.

Comment: Certainly I'd do it like you say, using a single model that represents both top level and child menu items. The top level elements would be those without a parent. It's easier like that. In that case you could use my proposed solution as well, it works too. BTW you can mark the answer as accepted if you feel like it ☺

Comment: Thanks for the reply again @ Jose_Tomas_Tocino.  One other quick question if I may.  I've used the command above to return the data.  Can you explain how I can access the information?  When i query it, i get [<Sub_Menu: Dance Classes>].  Where Dance Classes is a sub menu of classes.  Struggling to access the sub_menu models attributes through this data structure.  Thank you.

Comment: Uhm, I've realized you've changed the `related_name` setting of the ForeignKey to `name`, a rather bad name. In that case you need to use `yourmenu.name.all()`. Check this: http://codepad.org/ShzR5Gj2

Comment: Thanks again for your kind response. My last question and then I'll leave you alone ;-).  Can you just let me know why name is a bad name for me to use as my related_name. Also the code you shared, would that be based on my models or is that based on a different model to build the menu / submenu ? Thanks in advance, much appreciate it pal.

Comment: The code I've posted is with your models exactly. And I think that "name" is not a good name for the relation because it does not make much sense and doesn't inform about the purpose of the element. I'd rather use "children", "subitems" or something like that, so you could just use "MyMenu.subitems.all"

Comment: Penny has just dropped now pal, thanks very much for the additional response. Regards, Wayne